# Can we set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions in AWS Glue?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

AWS Glue documentation doesn't mention anything about spark.sql.shuffle.partitions (which is by default 200) and how to increase/decrease it? Is it even possible in AWS glue? Or are we stuck with 200 partitions? Is there any good documentation around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS Glue documentation is less than stellar... In fact, the AWS glue documentation tells you to explicitly not set configuration. However, as you'll see from most answers about AWS Glue infrastructure, the answer is indeed to set configuration.

You can do this multiple ways depending on your needs. Let's assume you want to set this value to 100.

1. You can add a job parameter to your glue job like so: `--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=100`
2. In your code you can explicitly update the sqlContext like so: `sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "100")`
3. In RDD or SparkSQL you can call `repartition` on your rdd object or dataframe like so `df.repartition(100)` or `rdd.repartition(100)`.
4. In RDD the various join methods take the parameter `numPartitions` that you can set like so: `rdd1.join(rdd1, numPartitions=100)`

Comment: Thanks Zambonilli..I was also hoping that without setting these configurations, it would be hard to work with AWS Glue...I will try setting as you mentioned :)